# C# Conditioning Difference In OR Operator

Tags: c#

What is the difference in both of the expressions ? Using brackets or not in this case. What is the difference ?

```
(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpouseCitizenType) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpouseNomPrenom)) &&
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpouseEGN);
```

---

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpouseCitizenType) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpouseNomPrenom) &&
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpouseEGN);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operator AND `&&` has a higher precendence than OR `||`. So, if we denote conditions used here as 1, 2 and 3, first line is equvalent to

```
(1 || 2) && 3
```

and the second

```
1 || (2 && 3)
```

For the full list of operators sorted in order of precedence check out this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: [Quick IDEOne](https://ideone.com/DK43cB) program that demonstrates the different output..